# How I save in a NSFileManager?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I have an application that uses json services and I would like to save this json in NSFileManager, that measure can have at most? There is a limit to size?

Comment: You don't use `NSFileManager` to save files. Please clarify what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what issue you are having.

Comment: you always can archive the entire structure (assuming every leaf conforms the `NSCoding` protocol), and anytime you can restore it back from the file.

Answer (score 0):

To save:

```
UIImage *pickedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);
NSString *withFullPathName = @"yourFullPathFileName";
[pngData writeToFile:withFullPathName atomically:YES];
```

Once you saved your data (imagine a photo), so you can use NSFileManager to read:

```
NSData* data;
NSString *fullPathName = @"yourFullPathFileName";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPathName]) {

    data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPathName];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
} else {
    NSLog(@"file does not exist.");
}

// When you set your fullPathName try make sure it is unique for each file.
```

**EDIT**

```
// Considering your JSON is a NSString: 

// 1. Convert the nsstring to nsdata
NSString* str = @"yourJsonAsString:{...}";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// You don't use nsfilemanager to save you use to read, you use "writeToFile:" to store your info.
[data writeToFile:@"yourFullPathName" atomically:YES];

// To read your file, use the example of the code above about NSFileManager.
// About the size, the only size limit is the amount of available space on the device. However is not a good pratice save a huge file. You should use core-data.
```

Comment: You really need to specify a full path when writing and reading the file.

Comment: Hey @rmaddy thanks for the comment. I improved my answer.

Comment: I would like to save a JSON in a NSFilemanager, is it possible? If the answer is YES, what is the max size that can have it?

Comment: @DavidTorguet I edited my code. See if it answers your question. thanks.